# How to pass integers and strings from MATLAB to a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, matlab, automated-tests

I need to automate a test. The test itself is being written (by me) in MATLAB, has 5 stages, each stage ends with setting a value to an integer (uint16_t and uint8_t) and with a message. I have to pass these 5 integers and 5 strings to a PowerShell script because Jenkins can only run a PowerShell or Python script, but I'm not entirely sure how can I achieve that. I have never used PS or done any scripting, and there isn't much on the Internet on how to even run a MATLAB script with PowerShell. (Maybe I should check batch file scripts running MATLAB scripts.)

The only option I've found so far is writing into a (temporary) file with MATLAB, then reading from it (and deleting it), it could be a .txt file, or preferably a .csv file (although using `csvwrite` is not recommended by Mathworks), but this isn't very reliable. Can anyone suggest other methods to pass it more directly? The MATLAB file is not a function, but it can be made to be one that has these variables as outputs. Also, it's fine if the integers are cast to another integer type.

Comment: [How to use parameters in PowerShell](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/how-to-use-parameters-in-powershell/).

Comment: Have MATLAB print to stdout in CSV format; in PS `$results = matlab.exe yourscript` (or however you end up running it) and then `ConvertFrom-Csv $results`.

Answer (score 1):

Like @TessellatingHeckler said the way is `$results = matlab.exe yourscript`.

Here is an example if you want more features when launch the tests like no display windows ,run in a batch mode or wait to the end of matlab execution.

```
runTestMatlab (){
   result=$(matlab.exe -wait -nosplash -noFigureWindows -batch TestScript.m)

   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
       # Error with the Matlab run
       echo $result
       return 1
   fi
   echo "$result"
   return 0
}
```

Then you can parse the result with awk or any other tool that you want.

Comment: With `-batch` you don’t need the other options. Even `-wait` is implied!